# Force compile time check for correct object instantiation

Tags: c++

How do I force the compiler to give errors if the user instantiates an object of some class incorrectly?

For example:

```
Polynomial a("x^2 + 2x + 1"); //this is a valid Polynomial object

Polynomial b("3xy + 2 - 5/z"); //this is not valid, force compiler error
```

`static_assert` seems to not work with function arguments and templates seem to not work with strings. If it's not possible to do this at compile-time, what are good ways to do this at run-time?

Comment: First write a `constexpr` function, which checks a `string_view` argument

Comment: There's some basic info on how you can do compile-time string contents validation on [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59805334/364696), but the short form is: It's almost certainly not worth the complexity to make it occur at compile time; writing proper unit tests would catch the runtime errors (along with testing the rest of your code), and it's a lot easier to do runtime errors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Read the first part of that clause about run-time errors; they want info on doing the run-time errors only if compile-time is impossible. That's a reasonable approach ("I'd like to do this, but if it's not possible, how do I do the other thing?"), though I'd consider basic run-time error-checking to be simple enough they should try to do that on their own, then ask how to convert it to compile-time checking (if possible).

Comment: @ShadowRanger -- OK, I reread the post.  However this: `what are good ways to do this at run-time?` is not clear, since I would have assumed the OP already has a function that does this.

Comment: The string can be converted into a 'checked_string' object, which does this check on compile-time (or optionally depending on the constness of the parameter at compile or runtime). The checked_string object just stores the parameter (be careful with object lifetimes, when storing pointer or reference) and is `constexpr`. If the parameters are wrong, it throws (which gives a compiler error). `Polynomial` uses `checked_string` as parameter type and can be sure that the parameter validated correctly. If the `checked_string` constructor is *not* explicit, the checked_string is inserted implicitly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The reason I said "what are good ways" is because I originally wrote "what is the best way" and I thought people would say there is no universal best practice. I can think of 2 ways of giving run-time time errors, throwing exceptions and assert(). I am a novice at programming and I just want to hear what experienced programmers have to say about this topic.

Comment: @christmascake -- So basically you're asking `SomeObject obj(some_parameters); ` and what to do if the constructor determines that the object is going to be unusable, given the parameters?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Precisely, in my example the constructor would look at the parameter passed to object b and check the string to find errors. It would find that a Polynomial object cannot have a term that divides by a variable and I would get a compile time error.

Comment: Then I would do as mentioned by @Sebastian -- write a function that takes a `string_view` that checks, and make it `constexpr`.  You will still be able to use the same function at runtime.  I think that's a separate issue than what to do with `Polynomial` once you've discovered that the string is not valid.

Comment: Personally I'd do something on the lines `Polynomial a = Term(coefficient, power) + Term(coefficient, power) + Term(coefficient, power);` with some fancy operator overloading and proxy objects. Although that wouldn't allow you to write polynomials in a natural fashion like `"(x - 1)(x - 2)"`.

Comment: ...unless you provided a `Root(value)` object. E.g. `Polynomial a = Root(1).Root(2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did read and read your question and comments and maybe I am confused what you want but why simple solution using constexpr constructor does not suit you:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Polynomial {
    const char* str;

    constexpr Polynomial(char const* arg) 
        : str(arg) {
        // if check fails when constructing constexpr Polynomial
        // we get compile error for throwing, otherwise works
        // if check fails when constructing runtime Polynomial
        // then it does throw
        if (arg[0] != 'b') throw 42; 
    }
};

int main() {
    // should compile as first character is 'b'
    constexpr Polynomial a("bar");
    const char* foo = "foo";
    try {
        // should throw as first character is not 'b'
        Polynomial b(foo);
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Q.E.D." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This AFAIK worked already in C++14.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it also explained that if "bar" were "car" (something that doesn't start with 'b') that it **doesn't throw an exception**, but rather that it **fails to compile** because `throw 42` _is not a constant expression_.

Comment: @Wyck I commented that within constructor body